# Error when returning partial view to ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple ajax call of a sort I have used many times, like this:

```
$.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Admin/RolePermission?roleId=" + itemid,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#dialog-RolePermission).html(result);
                }
            });
```

And after some standard stuff to find the object by its id and populate a model, i attempt to return the partial to the ajax call for the dialog thus:

```
return PartialView("_CreateOrEditRolePermissions", bgAll);
```

Now, as usual, having followed the standard protocol of placing the view in a folder with same name as the controller, I see the view name underlined in Visual Studio and all looks good - it has found the file...

Except I get the following error:

```
The partial view "some view name" was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations...

~/Views/RolePermission/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions.aspx
~/Views/RolePermission/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions.ascx
~/Views/Shared/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions.aspx
~/Views/Shared/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions.ascx
~/Views/RolePermission/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions.cshtml
~/Views/RolePermission/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions.vbhtml
```

This folder structure is working in other situations and I have tried moving the file to the shared folder, and giving a full file path and filetype suffix, like this:

```
return PartialView("~/Views/RolePermission/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions", model);
```

and this (which for some reason is the "browse to url shown in the file properties):

```
return PartialView("~/Admin/RolePermission/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions.cshtml", model);
```

EDIT:

My folder structure:

[image]

I'm sure this must be something simple and there are various questions on here which appear to be have the same issue but the solutions there are not working. Happy to provide extra detail if required, please just comment.

Comment: Complete error should also show list of searched locations - make sure it makes sense for your controller/action.

Comment: Updating to include full error with checked directories. it looks okay, and if it wasn't working i would expect other functions to be failing. it has me stumped!

Comment: Added a screenshot of my folder structure too...

Comment: No idea. Debug and see if there is anything strange... If IIS - check where site actually points to - maybe something happened and your site is looking in different folder.

Comment: Something wrong with your area usage. Without deep dive, quick and dirty fix may be to use absolute path: `return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/RolePermission/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions", model);`

Comment: Great idea @Dima...needed the full path, as you suggested, just with the .cshtml at the end. Still no idea why only in this scenario but write up as an answer and I'll give it to you. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something wrong with your area usage. Without deep dive, quick and dirty fix may be to use absolute path:

```
return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/RolePermission/_CreateOrEditRolePermissions.cshtml", model);
```